# Android Studio - transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug error

Tags: android, gradle

After updating from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6` I got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.util.NoSuchElementException (no error message)
```

I have `multiDexEnabled true`, which worked so far (up to `alpha3`); if I remove it I get another error:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':MyApp:zipalignDebug'.
> File '/Users/myuser/dev/projects/my-app/MyApp/build/outputs/apk/MyApp-debug-unaligned.apk' specified for property 'inputFile' does not exist.
```

Any clue?

Note: after updating to `alpha6` I also updated `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` and did a project clean + rebuild.

Comment: Same error. Updating to alpha6 is break the multidex...

Comment: Finally I discovered my Android Studio 2.0 Preview was outdated (I was in stable channel). I updated it to Preview 6 (canary channel). See: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: I also had to disable "instant run" due to other problem I had after updating Android Studio. Now I can start my app again, at least...

Comment: And it works after update?

Comment: I had this issue as well, but just disabling instant run solved the problem.  This error just happened when testing on Android 5+

Comment: Thanks Ferran Maylinch Its work for me too. After disable the "instant run" it solve my problem too.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too! Was scratching my head since past 4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add the answer, since it seems to work for some people.

I discovered that my Android Studio 2.0 Preview was outdated (I was in stable channel). I updated it to the [latest version](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest) (canary channel). At the moment is the Preview 6.

I also had to disable "instant run" due to other problem I had after updating Android Studio.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That moment when you want to include only one library and you end up updating android studio and everything (yes, I am looking at you google play)